# Open another window in xaml view in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I am new to Wpf and following the MVVM pattern to design my application. I have a ViewModel and an View. By the design, my View knows about my ViewModel and the reverse is not. If i want to open another window upon click of a button, i could use a command and when user clicks, that command will be routed to my ViewModel.

But how would i create a window that will have it's own view and ViewModel. I am kind of confused in this. I want to invoke the new window from Xaml itself as my ViewModel does not know about the another view and probably it's viewmodel.

To keep it simple,

```
View1 -> (bound to) ViewModel1
View1 -> Button1.Click -> Command(bound to) ViewModel1
---- how to open View2 -> (bound to) ViewModel2------
Show View2.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just call **Show** from the code-behind of View 1 to open View 2. The ViewModel from View 1 should not be involved.

Like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new View2().Show();
}
```

Your next thought might be "isn't this violating MVVM?" No, I wouldn't say so. The ViewModel should not have any direct control of UI elements if it is to be considered a clean implementation of MVVM. If you want something in the ViewModel to trigger the Window to open you can always use events or a 3rd party library like Caliburn to easily implement this without worrying about coupling.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i suggest to do that.because of there are no dependancy with view in another view model .simply you can write a dialog services to open any of view as popup(window).
normaly `Show()` method use the `System.Windows` dependancy so better to use as service and then we can Unit test our application.

```
    public interface IDialogService
    {
        BaseViewModel ShowTitleDialog(BaseViewModel viewModel, UserControl view, string windowTitle);
    }

    public class DialogService : IDialogService
    {
        public BaseViewModel ShowTitleDialog(BaseViewModel viewModel, UserControl view, string windowTitle)
        {
            if (view == null && viewModel == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("view is null");
            }

            RegisterTemplate(viewModel.GetType(), view.GetType());
            return ShowTitleDialog(viewModel, windowTitle);
        }
        private void RegisterTemplate(Type viewModelType, Type viewType)
        {
            const string xamlTemplate = "<DataTemplate DataType=\"{{x:Type vm:{0}}}\"><v:{1} /></DataTemplate>";
            var xaml = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, xamlTemplate, viewModelType.Name, viewType.Name, viewModelType.Namespace, viewType.Namespace);

            var context = new ParserContext();

            context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]);
            context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("vm", viewModelType.Namespace, viewModelType.Assembly.FullName);
            context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("v", viewType.Namespace, viewType.Assembly.FullName);

            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("vm", "vm");
            context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("v", "v");

            var template = (DataTemplate)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
            var key = template.DataTemplateKey;
            Application.Current.Resources[key] = template;
        }

        public BaseViewModel ShowTitleDialog(BaseViewModel viewModel, string windowTitle, bool isEnableScrollBars = false)
        {
            Window window = new Window();
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            ContentControl contentControl = new ContentControl();
            contentControl.Content = viewModel;

            if (!isEnableScrollBars)
            {
                window.Content = contentControl;
                window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight; window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                ScrollViewer scrollViewver = new ScrollViewer();
                scrollViewver.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                scrollViewver.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                scrollViewver.Content = contentControl;
                window.Height = 600;
                window.MaxHeight = 600;
                window.Content = scrollViewver;
            }

            window.Title = windowTitle;
            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

            window.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<System.Windows.Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMouseOver);
            window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            window.ShowDialog();
            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

Usage..

```
    class TestAViewModel
    {
      public void ClickEvent()
      {
        TestBViewModel viewModel = new TestBViewModel();
        viewModel.ShowThisView();
      }
    }

    class TestBViewModel
    {
      public void ShowThisView()
      {
         TestBViewModel viewModel = new TestBViewModel();
         TestBView view = new TestBView();
         view.DataContext = viewModel;

         IDialogService dialogCheckIn = new DialogService();
         dialogCheckIn.ShowTitleDialog(viewModel, view, "Title");
      }
    }
```